# Gravação Arquivo Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, pl-sql, oracle12c

Bom dia,

Sou iniciante em Oracle PL/SQL, e criei o script abaixo para gravar o resultado de uma consulta em arquivo txt, executa sem erros porem não grava o arquivo, alguém sabe o que poderia estar acontecendo ? Onde estou errando ?

```
DECLARE arquivo_saida
UTL_File.File_Type; Cursor Cur_Linha is   Select OWNER||'  '||TABLE_NAME as Linha From All_Tables Where Owner Like'SYS%';
BEGIN arquivo_saida := UTL_File.Fopen('C:\teste','arquvo.txt','w');   
For Reg_Linha in Cur_linha Loop
UTL_File.Put_Line(arquivo_saida, Reg_linha.linha);
End Loop; 
UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);   
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Arquivo gerado com sucesso.');
EXCEPTION
WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Operação inválida no arquivo.'); 
UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
WHEN UTL_FILE.WRITE_ERROR THEN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Erro de gravação no arquivo.');
UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Diretório inválido.');
UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE THEN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Modo de acesso inválido.');
UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida); 
WHEN Others THEN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Problemas na geração do arquivo.');
UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
END;
```

Comment: Foi definido a pasta UTL ou diretory no Oracle ? https://www.devmedia.com.br/pacote-utl_file-do-oracle/13129  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm

Comment: Será que não tem que ser 'C:\teste\' do que 'C:\teste'?

Comment: @Motta seu link foi super útil, necessitava apenas setar o diretório antes de utilizar: CREATE DIRECTORY DIRETORIO AS 'C:\DIRETORIO';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme comentei na resposta do @motta, faltou a criação do diretório de saída com o comando abaixo:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY DIRETORIO AS 'C:\DIRETORIO';
```

Então substitui-se o caminho pela variável:

```
BEGIN arquivo_saida := UTL_File.Fopen('DIRETORIO','arquvo.txt','w');
```